# ¿Cómo hacer correr un programa en gedit / Ubuntu C++ desde la terminal?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

Estoy usando gedit en Ubuntu14.04 en C++, hago correr el programa desde la terminal pero aroja error:

```
g++: error: prueba.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files 
compilation terminated.
```

He buscando en internet y dice que tengo que configurar external tools manager, he probado con todos los codigos para compilar, correr y compilar y correr pero no funciona. Por favor podrian ayudarme con esto.

Comment: Gedit es un editor de texto, no puede ejecutar un programa a través de él. Puede usar gedit para editar el código fuente del programa y compilarlo y ejecutarlo a través de la terminarl con el compilador `g++` por ejemplo. Si amplia o aclara la pregunta puedo proveerle la información más adecuada.

Comment: @Nas_04 El problema puede encontrase en que, al usar la terminal, no estás ubicado en el mismo directorio donde guardaste el archivo `prueba.cpp`. Tienes que estar en el mismo directorio para que el comando funcione. Aquí hay más información acerca de [cómo moverte por los directorios en Ubuntu](https://ubuntuparanovatos.wordpress.com/2007/06/11/navega-por-tus-directorios-desde-la-terminal/). Cuando estés en el mismo directorio, puedes usar `ls` para ver si se encuentra `prueba.cpp, e intentar de nuevo.

Comment: Considera también que `prueba.cpp` es el nombre que yo puse de ejemplo, tienes que usar el nombre del archivo que tu tienes localmente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, desde `gedit` no creo que puedas hacerlo ya que es simplemente un editor de texto. Lo que tienes que hacer es compilarlo desde tu terminal usando [`g++`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%2B%2B).

Por ejemplo, considera el siguiente código en el archivo `prueba.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "¡Hola, mundo!\n";
}
```

Para compilarlo, ubícate en la ruta en donde se encuentra tu archivo `prueba.cpp`:

```
$ g++ prueba.cpp -o prueba
```

Esto te generara un archivo ejecutable llamado `prueba` (gracias a la opción `-o`).

```
$ ls -l
total 40
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cesar cesar 9001 mar 18 10:53 prueba
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cesar cesar   71 mar 18 10:52 prueba.cpp
```

Luego, solo queda ejecutarlo:

```
$ ./prueba
¡Hola, mundo!
```

Aca puedes encontrar una pequeña guía para compilar:

- [Compiling C++ programs with g++](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~jestes/howto/g++compiling.txt)

### Actualización

Es posible que necesites instalar el paquete para `g++` previamente. Desde tu terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential g++
```

Comment: Yo hago todo eso pero sale error que no hay archivo y no se porque

Comment: @Nas_04 Podrías editar tu pregunta y mostrarnos tu código, así como describir paso a paso lo que estás haciendo y qué error te marca la computadora?

Comment: @Nas_04 asumo que tienes g++ build-essential "o las librerias que necesites" asi que cuando dices no hay archivo te refieres a que no encuentra el fichero cuando haces ./prueba si es asi fijate que lleva un punto y tienes que esta en el directorio donde estan los ficheros

Comment: Si, ese paquete esta actualizado. Buscando en internet dice que tengo que configurar external tools manager,  he probado todos con todos los codigos para compilar, correr y compilar y correr pero no funciona.

Comment: @Nas_04 actualiza tu pregunta con toda esa información para saber qué y cómo lo estás haciendo, qué errores te arroja, etc.

Answer (score 3):

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:** El problema puede encontrase en que, al usar la terminal, no estás ubicado en el mismo directorio donde guardaste el archivo prueba.cpp. Tienes que estar en el mismo directorio para que el comando funcione. Aquí hay más información acerca de [cómo moverte por los directorios en Ubuntu](https://ubuntuparanovatos.wordpress.com/2007/06/11/navega-por-tus-directorios-desde-la-terminal/). Cuando estés en el mismo directorio, puedes usar ls para ver si se encuentra `prueba.cpp, e intentar de nuevo.

Para correr un programa de C++, necesitas de un compilador de C++, como `g++`. Lo instalas corriendo `sudo apt-get install build-essential` en una terminal, o buscando el paquete `build-essential` en el Ubuntu Software Center. Con el compilador, produces un archivo binario, que es el que corres.

Gedit te sirve más que nada como editor, aunque de hecho tiene una opción de correr el comando `make` con la tecla F8 o F9, si mal no recuerdo. Si no te es familiar el concepto de `make` y `makefile`, no vendría mal [leer al respecto](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/tools-make.html). Si no te es familiar el concepto de compilar código de `C++`, pues también [tienes que leer](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~beechung/ref/gcc-intro.html), es muy importante.

Si lo que quieres es un programa que te sirva para editar código, compilar y ejecutar el programa, necesitas un IDE completo, como [Eclipse CDT](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/mars2) o [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/downloads/). Estos programas pueden detectar los compiladores que tengas, configurar todas las opciones de compilación y linking que sean relevantes para tu proyecto, y hacerlo automáticamente al dar click a un botón. Sólo ten presente que estos programas no son nada ligeros.

Lo que yo hago es hacer todo desde la terminal, como lo platica César en la otra respuesta. Cuando es un proyecto un poco más serio y no se trata de una simple prueba, uso `GNU make`.

Comment: Esta debería ser la respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque no es exactamente lo que pides, puedes tener un terminal empotrado en gedit. Para ello debes instalar los plugins de gedit

```
sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins
```

Si luego vas a preferencias podrás seleccionar "terminal empotrado". Esta terminal te aparece y desaparece con la combinación de teclado

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>

Es una manera cómoda de tener un terminal en el que realizar pruebas de compilación y ejecución de tu programa o script. Pero antes asegúrate que el terminal está en la ruta adecuada.